# xamarin: binding object and object parent to property change

Tags: xamarin

I have a model "optionModel" with "data" member as a list of "options". Option has title and status members:

```
class optionModel
{
...
    public List<option> data {get; private set;}
}

class option
{
...
    public String title{get;set}
    public bool status {get;set}
}
```

My view for the model is a grid, which is populating like this:

```
optionModel _m = new optionModel();
Grid g = new Grid();
foreach (option op in _m.data)
{
..
    TextSwitch tc = new TextSwitch(); // view class
    tc.BindingContext = op;
        tc.SetBinding(TextSwitch.IsToggledProperty, "status");
    g.Children.Add(tc, 0, iRow);
        ..
}
```

Everything works as expected. "status" property of the "option" is updated, I am happy.

**My question is**: In addition to "option" I also want "optionModel" to be notified when any of the "option" change their status. One immediate solution is
to construct the "option" to have pointer to the optionModel and notify optionModel it within "status" set method of "option".

But perhaps there is a way to do it via Xamarin binding mechanism without introducing optionModel as a member of "option"?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe you can raise an event when the property changed and then process it in optionModel

Comment: Yes, that falls into standard .net solution. I was wandering if there is Xamarin-specific solution using "binding" mechanism.

Comment: The Xamarin bindings uses `PropertyChanged` notifications to handle bindings to properties, so you would be using the same technique they are.